# Number of solution set such that $a \geq b \geq c \geq d \geq 0$; $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a + b + c + d = 10$

Tags: combinatorics

Given $(a, b, c, d)$ is a set of integers and $a \geq b \geq c \geq d \geq 0$. Find the number of solution sets for $a + b + c + d = 10$.

(This is problem from a competition, the answer key says its $23$, wherein my answer is $455$)

Solution

$x_1 + x_2 +1 + x_3 + 2 + x_4 + 3 = 10$

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 16$

$_{15}C_3$ = 455

Comment: Edit the question to show your solution so we can critique it.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Solution shown...

Comment: You should have subtracted rather than added, which gives $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 4$, an equation with $35$ solutions.

Comment: Your solution is incomrehensible.  What are the $x_1x_2,x_3,x_4$ and why do when you add 1,2 and 3 to the sum do you get $1$.  Why is the number of solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 16$ $_{15}C_3$?

Comment: May I ask when do I add or when do I subtract, I'm not really familiar with thus rule?

Comment: When you add on the right hand side, you also add on the left hand side. When you subtract one the right hand side, you also subtract on the left hand side. You added on the right hand side and subtracted on the left hand side.

Comment: Given the restriction what value should I subtract from each side?

Comment: You should explain what you are doing instead of writing down lines of equations with no comments at all.

Comment: I assumed that the numbers cannot be equal to each other, therefore adding to assure that one will be greater than the other

Comment: The answer is the number of partitions of 10 with 4 or fewer parts, which is 23.

Comment: This site is not really intended as a place to post competition problems, unless you can also give some motivation for why the problem is interesting. There are other sites that focus more on "challenge" problems that may not have a clear motivation.

Comment: @Jens is there formula for this? I tried to look for it, but can't find anything.

Comment: @Kusavil: Not that I know of. I simply have an algorithm to find these partitions. It's based on info I found [here](http://teaching.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS7209/partition.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The solutions are:
$$\begin{align}(d,c,b,a)=
&(0,0,0,10) \cdots (0,0,5,5) \Rightarrow 6 \\ 
&(0,1,1,8) \cdots (0,1,4,5) \Rightarrow 4 \\
&(0,2,2,6), (0,2,4,4) \Rightarrow 3 \\
&(0,3,3,4) \Rightarrow 1  \\
&(1,1,1,7) \cdots (1,1,4,4) \Rightarrow 4 \\
&(1,2,2,5), (1,2,3,4) \Rightarrow 2 \\
&(1,3,3,3) \Rightarrow 1 \\
&(2,2,2,4),(2,2,3,3) \Rightarrow 2 \end{align}$$
Hence, there are $23$ solutions.

Comment: is there some easy way or formula to do this? What, if instead of $a,b,c,d$ we had $x_1,...,x_k$ and we were to solve $x_1+\dots+x_k = n$, where $0 \le x_1 \le \dots \le x_k$?

Answer (score 1):

$a \geq b \geq c \geq d \geq 0$ give easily as follows
$$\begin{cases}a=10\text{ gives } 1\\a=9\text{ gives } 1\\a=8\text{ gives }2\\a=7\text{ gives }3\\a=6\text{ gives }4\\a=5\text{ gives }5\\a=4\text{ gives }5\\a=3\text{ gives }2
\end{cases}$$
**examples**: $8200,8110\text{ are the two solutions for a=8 }\\ 5500,5410,5320,5311,5221\text{ are the five solutions for a=5 }$

Thus there are $23$ solutions.